# Какую среду разработки использовать, чтобы для запуска не требовались библиотеки на Windows?

Tags: windows, ide, exe

Какие среды разработки и языки программирования можно использовать, чтобы для запуска приложения не требовались библиотеки (или они уже были встроены в exe или Windows), фреймворки и т.п. (просто exe-шник)?

Подходит Pascal (Delphi), но нужно, что-то более современное. Пробовал C#, но для него нужен Microsoft .NET Framework. Для Java нужна установленая Java.

Comment: С/С++ в Visual Studio. Но все равно придется прилагать усилия.

Comment: Да тоже пробовал, с консольным приложением получалось, а вот с формами? С CLI или что нужно? и как вообще лучше делать?

Comment: И с формами тоже можно, только вы не приложили усилий.